# Existiert das Verb "sich belesen"?

Tags: meaning

Kürzlich bin ich über den folgenden Satz gestolpert:

> Ihre Konkurrenz beliest sich auch.

Das Verb "belesen" kann ich allerdings nirgends finden, selbst bei Grimm findet man nur Folgendes

> depurgare, emundare, rein lesen: das gemüse, den salat belesen; die linsen sind nicht ordentlich belesen. in diesem sinn ahd. arlesan (Graff 2, 248).

Was heißt der obige Satz und findet das Verb "(sich) belesen" Verwendung?

Comment: Belies dich mal da: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/belesen (unter "Herkunft")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Siehe etwa im Duden-Universalwörterbuch zum Adjektiv "belesen":

> be|le|sen 〈Adjektiv〉 [eigentlich 2. Partizip von veraltet belesen = durchlesen] [...]

In der Bedeutung ist der Begriff auch bei Grimm verzeichnet (als Bedeutung 2), siehe [hier](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB?bookref=1,1446,16):

> 2) *librum legere, perlegere* [...]

Einen reflexiven Gebrauch i.S.v. "sich durch Lesen weiterbilden" - was wohl im Beispielsatz gemeint ist -  findet man im Idiotikon [nachgewiesen](https://digital.idiotikon.ch/idtkn/id3.htm#!page/31417/mode/1up):

> refl., durch Lesen seine Kenntnisse erweitern [...]

In COSMAS (W-ohneWikipedia-öffentlich) lässt sich auf den ersten Blick zumindest bei einer Recherche der verbdistinkten Wortformen keine nennenswerte heutige Verwendung feststellen, außer beim *Nordkurier*, der für fast alle Korpusnachweise verantwortlich zeichnet, möglicherweise also einen Belesenheitsnostalgiker unter seinen Autoren hat ...