# Gibt es eine bestimmte Bezeichnung für Adjektive, die aussehen wie ein Partizip?

Tags: adjective, terminology, participle

Anlässlich [dieser](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/40910/existiert-das-verb-sich-belesen) Frage:

Im Deutschen gibt es eine Anzahl Adjektive, die der Form nach aussehen und auch grammatikalisch behandelt werden wie ein Partizip, allerdings keines sein können, weil das zugehörige Verb nicht mehr existiert oder niemals existiert hat, wie z. B.:

1. *maniriert* (es gibt *Manier,* aber nicht *manirieren*)
2. *exaltiert* (hier finde ich weder ein Substantiv, noch ein deutsches Verb dazu)
3. *belesen* (es gibt kein Verb *belesen,* oder wenigstens nicht mehr)
4. *verwandt* (im Sinne von *Verwandtschaft* – *verwenden* würde als Verb passen, hat aber eine vollkommen andere Bedeutung)
5. *beredt (bereden* ist mir nicht als Verb bekannt, oder wenn, dann würde das Partizip moderner gebildet wie in: »Wir haben das beredet«)
6. *verschroben* (hier scheint es ein Verb *verschreben* oder *verschrauben* gegeben zu haben)

Bezeichnet man solche Adjektive als Partizipien, obwohl es kein »passendes« Verb dafür gibt oder nicht mehr gibt? Verliert ein Partizip diese Eigenschaft, wenn sein zugehöriges Verb ausstirbt? Oder haben diese Wörter eine eigene Bezeichnung? Oder sind es einfach Adjektive?

Comment: Ich vermute mal, dass die ersten zwei aus anderen Sprachen (z.B. Französisch) übernommen wurden, und da schon die Partizip-Form hatten. Gilt nicht für die anderen, natürlich. Da sind es wohl ausgestorbene Verben gewesen (oder so ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es gibt dafür die Bezeichnung *Scheinpartizipien* oder auch *Pseudopartizipien*.

Eine Quelle dafür: http://canoonet.eu/services/Controller?dispatch=glossary&input=Scheinpartizip&language=0&project=1

Comment: Ich kannte den Begriff nicht. Allerdings beschreibt LEOs deutsche Grammatik (dorthin wurde die Grammatik von canoo verschoben) die Pseudopartizipien als solche, die *nicht* von einem Verb, sondern von einem Nomen abgeleitet werden. Das ist aber in den Beispielen von tofro (sofern ich es abschätzen kann) nur bei 1 der Fall (und selbst da bin ich nicht sicher).